# Error Not unique table/alias: Multiple Join Laravel

Tags: laravel, join

Tengo un problema al intentar hacer múltiple join a la misma tabla pero con diferente dato.

```
$comentarios = DB::table('ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios')
            ->join('usuarios_embajadores','usuarios_embajadores.id','=','ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios.comment_user_id')
            ->join('usuarios_embajadores','usuarios_embajadores.id','=','ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios.comment_user_response_id')
            ->select('ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios.id','usuarios_embajadores.nombre','comentario','respuesta','ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios.created_at')
            ->where('id_mejora', $id)
            ->get();
```

BDD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El la columna `comment_user_id` necesito un `join` a `usuarios_embajadores` así como también otro `join` para `comment_user_response_id`a la misma tabla.

pero esto me ocasiona un error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique
>   table/alias: 
>       'usuarios_embajadores' (SQL: select `ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios`.`id`,
>   `usuarios_embajadores`.`nombre`, `comentario`, `respuesta`,
>   `ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios`.`created_at` from
>   `ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios` inner join
>   `usuarios_embajadores` on `usuarios_embajadores`.`id` =
>   `ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios`.`comment_user_id` inner join
>   `usuarios_embajadores` on `usuarios_embajadores`.`id` =
>   `ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios`.`comment_user_response_id` where
>   `id_mejora` = 9)

**¿Como puedo hacerlo?**

Comment: ¿Por qué no hacerlo con Eloquent? Es realmente muy sencillo hacer este tipo de consultas.

Comment: Te estas olvidando de poner el "on" despues del `Join`

Comment: no @Dohko19 así como tiene la sintaxis del `join` es correcta en Laravel

Comment: Soluciones compañeros! porfavor!

Comment: Tiene dos joins a la misma tabla por lo cuál MySQL no sabe que tabla tomar para seleccionar el nombre, Intente añadir alias a las tablas del join `->join('usuarios_embajadores as tbl1', .... )` y en el `select`accedería al alias `tbl1.nombre`

Answer (score 1):

En su consulta tiene dos `joins` a la misma tabla por lo cuál MySQL no sabe que tabla tomar para seleccionar el nombre. Para estos casos sería mejor añadir `aliases` a las tablas y no haya problemas.

Para añadir aliases en el `join` en el primer parámetro donde indica el nombre de la tabla con la palabra reservada `as mialias`

Ejm *(Como recomendación, con relaciones bien definidas en sus modelos sería más sencillo obtener los datos utilizando Eloquent que utilizar query Builder)* en el ejemplo se asume que `id_mejora` es campo único, si no podría causar error en caso se repitiese en más de 1 tabla de la consulta.

```
$comentarios = DB::table('ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios')
            ->join('usuarios_embajadores as tbl1','tbl1.id',
                    '=','ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios.comment_user_id')
            ->join('usuarios_embajadores as tbl2','tbl2.id',
                   '=','ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios.comment_user_response_id')
            ->select('ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios.id','tbl1.nombre',
                      'comentario','respuesta',
                      'ventana_abierta_mejoras_comentarios.created_at')
            ->where('id_mejora', $id)
            ->get();
```